How to save files generated using Aspose with a browser?
so recently I'm working on the Aspose and encounter the problem.
I was using .NET Framework 4.8 & Aspose.Cells 24.4.0
I'm able to save the file directly in my local drive, but can't save by browser.
I'm wondering how to fix it, and do I need to do something in my front-end ?
Below is my code:
I was using AJAX to post formdata so that can get the parameter I need.
**.cshtml
**
@section forms {
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "UserExport", null, new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "alertSuccess"
    }, new { id = "frmExport" }))
    ...
    ...
}

Call function in controller
UserExportController.cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult Create(UserExportModel form, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploader)
{
    using (UserExportDac dac = new UserExportDac(GetLoginUser()))
    {
        IList<UserModel> userList = dac.ReadAll();
        if (form.isExcel == "Y"){
           dac.ExportExcel(userList);
        }
        
        ...
        ...
        return Json(new { message = "Generatedd file successfly!" });
    }
}

Using Aspose
UserExportDac.cs
 public void ExportExcel(IList<UserModel> userList)
 {     
     Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

     int index = workbook.Worksheets.Add();
     Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[index];

     worksheet.Name = "EMP_USER";

     // Generate the content...
     ...
     ...

     **// This work when I try saving in my local downloads**
     // string filePath = System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%/downloads/") + "EMP_USER_COPY.xls";
     // workbook.Save(filePath);

     // Below sample is query from the web, but didn't work me
     MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
     byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();

     HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
     response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
     response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "EMP_USER_COPY.xlsx";
     response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("Application/x-msexcel");
     workbook.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response, "EMP_USER_COPY.xlsx", Aspose.Cells.ContentDisposition.Attachment, new OoxmlSaveOptions(Aspose.Cells.SaveFormat.Xlsx));
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
 }

So currently I was stuck in the saving step.
Any advice would be appreciate it, thanks!!

You may try either of the (below) code snippets:
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

int index = workbook.Worksheets.Add();
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[index];

worksheet.Name = "EMP_USER";

// Generate the content...
...
...

//Send workbook to response
workbook.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response, "EMP_USER_COPY.xlsx", ContentDisposition.Attachment, new OoxmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Xlsx));
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

OR
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

int index = workbook.Worksheets.Add();
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[index];

worksheet.Name = "EMP_USER";

// Generate the content...
...
...

//Send workbook to response
OoxmlSaveOptions xSaveOptions = new OoxmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Xlsx);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
workbook.Save(ms, xSaveOptions);

//set the position.
ms.Position = 0;

this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
this.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=EMP_USER_COPY.xlsx");
Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
Response.End();

See the document for your further reference. Let us know if you still find any issue.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Hi Amjad, thanks for answering :)
I had tried the first solution, but the browser didn't generated the excel file automatically.
I checked the DevTools, Headers seems to be success:
General
...
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
...
Response Headers
Cache-Control:private
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="EMP_USER_COPY.xlsx"
Content-Length:8784
Content-Type:application/xlsx
Date:Wed, 24 Apr 2024 08:14:08 GMT
...

But checked the Preview only seen garbled text like this
PK      ! �sI Q  f!   $ xl/theme/theme1.xml
@��\� @��\� @��\��Z[o�6�+��]�$_����M�$-j�C���P�!�I����>�e��n�ˀ��aV`V�e?&@���;�d���6m�bÒ �D���s�9"u��Ð:�8�E-�|��:8� �f-��hPh�(�
I'm wondering if that is not the problem of the code but other issue ?

Could you please try to use ContentDisposition.Inline instead. See and try the following line of code:
workbook.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response, "EMP_USER_COPY.xlsx", ContentDisposition.Inline, new OoxmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Xlsx));
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
Also, did you try the second approach if it works?

Turn out it's the problem of using AJAX in my case, I change to the traditional submit post and both of the snippets worked. Thanks for saving my day !!
